# Minimum value of a sin function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, maxima-minima

How can I find the minimum value of this function:

\begin{equation}
      f(x)= \sin \left(x + \frac{π}{4} \right) + k
\end{equation}
I found the derivative and equated it to 0 but I got the answer wrong.

\begin{equation}
      0 = \cos \left(x + \frac{π}{4} \right) 
\end{equation}
Its a non-calculator question. How do I get to the answer using my method or another method? Thanks

Comment: sine of anything can range from -1 to +1

Comment: The range of the sine function is $[-1,1]$.  Assuming that $k$ is a constant, then the minimum of $\sin(x+\pi/4) + k$ is $k-1$.  No derivatives necessary.

Comment: As suggested by @XanderHenderson, this is best solved graphically.

Comment: Using your method, $\cos(x+\pi/4)=0 \implies \sin(x+\pi/4)=\pm 1$. After that, it should be fairly easy to find the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sin(x+\pi/4)$ has minimum $-1$, therefore $\sin(x+\pi/4)+k$ has minimum $\color{red}{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ so you have to solve $$f'(x)=\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$$

Comment: sorry i typed the question wrongly, it should be sin (x + π/4), and not sin (x + π/2). does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want $\alpha=x+π/2$ so that $$\cos(\alpha)=0.$$ This occurs when $\alpha=nπ/2$, where $n$ is an odd integer.

Note that this merely gives you the points where $f(x)$ is either maximum or minimum. To find the points where the function is at its minimum you'll have to differentiate $f'(x)$ too.

For all these points of the domain where $f$ is minimum, $f=k-1.$